# Magento - How do I get a list of all allowed countries in optionsarray?

Tags: magento

I can get countries like this:

```
$countryCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getResourceCollection()->loadByStore();
```

And they are listed somewhere in the object, but, how do I `toOptionsArray` them out?

I'm after **only the options per website** rather than complete list
*i.e. I want Angola, Antarctica and so on out of the list. (Sorry Angolans and penguins.)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Its actually the obvious answer:

```
$countryList = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getResourceCollection()
                                                  ->loadByStore()
                                                  ->toOptionArray(true);
```

also check out http://fishpig.co.uk/magento-tutorials/list-countries-for-drop-down-in-magento for more info on creating drop-down lists and such with the country list.

Comment: D'uh! I had 'options' instead of 'option'. Thanks for giving me an answer so quickly, and I am glad I at least tried, to fall down with a typo!

Comment: Setting the toOptionArray method's parameter to True adds also an empty element as first item of the countries. Somehow in my case it had a label "1", don't know why.

Comment: Found out why the "1" appeared. The "toOptionArray" accepts one parameter, which is either False, either a string which will be the label for the first - empty - element. So when you will put True as parameter, you will get "(string)True" which is "1".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
                                                                    ->loadData()
                                                                    ->toOptionArray(false);
                  $allowed = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/allow');
               if (count($_countries) > 0) { ?>
           <div class="input-box">
                                        <select name="country" id="country" class="validate-select" title="Country" >
                                        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
     <?php foreach($_countries as $_country){
                                            if(!in_array($_country['value'],explode(',',$allowed))){
                                                continue;
                                            } ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $_country['value']; ?>" <?php echo $formData['country'] == $_country['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>
                                                <?php echo $_country['label'] ?>
                                            </option>
                                        <?php
                                        } ?>
                                    </select>
                                <?php } ?>
```